# How to get the length of character type variable in RPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, variable-length

Is there any easy way to directly return the length of character and type variable in RPGLE? The length I am talking about here is not the length specified in the D-spec. I am talking about the actual number of meaningful characters in a string. Let's say a character type variable is defined to be 50 characters long, and it is assigned with value 'Hello world!', then the length I want is 12, which is from 'H' to '!'. The leading and trailing blank is ignored. Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `%len(%trimr(field))`, which trims trailing spaces before checking the length.

- `%triml` trims leading spaces (on the left)
- `%trimr` trims trailing spaces (on the right)
- `%trim` trims leading and trailing spaces

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the field you are trying to find the length of is a fixed character field, like

```
     dmsg              s             40a
```

If we do an eval msg = 'Hello, World!' then msg does not contain 'Hello, World!' - it contains 'Hello, World!                           '  That is, it has a pile of blanks to pad it out to 40 characters.  That's how fixed length fields work by definition.

%trimr() can work very well with these, and it even has an optional parameter to define which characters should be trimmed.

On the other hand, if you were to use a varying length field

```
     dmsg              s             40a   Varying
```

and then did an eval msg = 'Hello, World!' then the field actually contains only the characters assigned to it.  In this case, no %trimr() is needed; %len() will return the current length of the field.